# Nek5000: makenek error for boundary conditions code in .usr file

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, fortran

I am doing a Nek5000 simulation to run a case with two overlapping meshes (NekNek).

For mesh generation, I am modifying the mesh and adding force to the flow. In the .usr file, for boundary conditions in subroutine usrbc, the code I enter is as follows:

```
     subroutine userbc(ix,iy,iz,iside,eg) ! set up boundary conditions
c
c     NOTE ::: This subroutine MAY NOT be called by every process
c
      implicit none

      integer ix,iy,iz,iside,eg
      integer e

      include 'SIZE'
      include 'TOTAL'
      include 'NEKUSE'
      include 'NEKNEK'

     e = gllel(eg)

     if (imask(ix,iy,iz,e).eq.0) then
      ux   = 0.0
      uy   = 0.0
      uz   = 0.0
      temp = 0.0
     else
      ux = valint(ix,iy,iz,e,1)
      uy = valint(ix,iy,iz,e,2)
      uz = valint(ix,iy,iz,e,3)
      if (nfld_neknek.gt.3) temp = valint(ix,iy,iz,e,ldim+2)
     endif

      return
      end
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
      e = gllel(eg)
       1
Error: Syntax error in COMMON statement at (1)
/home/qasim/Nek5000/run/overlap/hillpnn.f:97:6:

       temp = 0.0
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
/home/qasim/Nek5000/run/overlap/hillpnn.f:102:6:

       uz = valint(ix,iy,iz,e,3)
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
makefile:129: recipe for target 'usrfile' failed
make: *** [usrfile] Error 1
```

The only file I edited from the `include` statement was the SIZE file. The code is:

```
c
c     Include file to dimension static arrays
c     and to set some hardwired run-time parameters
c
      integer ldim,lx1,lxd,lx2,lx1m,lelg,lelt,lpmin,ldimt,lpmax
      integer lpelt,lbelt,toteq,lcvelt
      integer lelx,lely,lelz,mxprev,lgmres,lorder,lhis
      integer maxobj,lpert,nsessmax,lxo
      integer lfdm,ldimt_proj,lelr

      ! BASIC
      parameter (ldim=2)               ! domain dimension (2 or 3)
      parameter (lx1=8)                ! GLL points per element along each direction
      parameter (lxd=12)               ! GL  points for over-integration (dealiasing)
      parameter (lx2=lx1)            ! GLL points for pressure (lx1 or lx1-2)

      parameter (lelg=22*8)            ! max number of global elements
      parameter (lpmin=1)              ! min number of MPI ranks
      parameter (lpmax=4)              ! max
      parameter (lelt=lelg/lpmin + 3)  ! max number of local elements per MPI rank
      parameter (ldimt=1)              ! max auxiliary fields (temperature + scalars)

      ! OPTIONAL
      parameter (ldimt_proj=1)         ! max auxiliary fields residual projection
      parameter (lelr=lelt)            ! max number of local elements per restart file
      parameter (lhis=1)               ! max history/monitoring points
      parameter (maxobj=1)             ! max number of objects
      parameter (lpert=1)              ! max number of perturbations
      parameter (toteq=1)              ! max number of conserved scalars in CMT
      parameter (nsessmax=2)           ! max sessions to NEKNEK
      parameter (lxo=lx1)              ! max GLL points on output (lxo>=lx1)
      parameter (mxprev=20)            ! max dim of projection space
      parameter (lgmres=30)            ! max dim Krylov space
      parameter (lorder=3)             ! max order in time
      parameter (lx1m=1)               ! GLL points mesh solver
      parameter (lfdm=0)               ! unused
      parameter (lelx=1,lely=1,lelz=1) ! global tensor mesh dimensions

      parameter (lbelt=1)              ! lelt for mhd
      parameter (lpelt=1)              ! lelt for linear stability
      parameter (lcvelt=1)             ! lelt for cvode

      ! INTERNALS
      include 'SIZE.inc'
```

The `include` files that have a `common` statement are `NEKNEK` and `NEKUSE`. Their codes are as follows:

```
c     NEKNEK
c     Multimesh variables
c
      integer intflag(2*ldim,lelt)
      common /intflag/ intflag

      integer imask(lx1,ly1,lz1,lelt)
      common /intmask/ imask 

      real             valint(lx1,ly1,lz1,lelt,nfldmax_nn)
      common /valmask/ valint

      integer igeom
      common /cgeom/ igeom

      integer nfld_neknek
      common /inbc/ nfld_neknek

      real bdrylg(lx1*ly1*lz1*lelt,nfldmax_nn,0:2)
      common /mybd/ bdrylg

      real    rst(nmaxl_nn*ldim)
      common /multipts_r/ rst 

      integer rcode(nmaxl_nn),elid(nmaxl_nn)
     $    ,proc(nmaxl_nn),ilist(1,nmaxl_nn),npoints_nn
      common /multipts_i/ rcode,elid,proc,ilist,npoints_nn

      integer inth_multi2
      common /intp_h_nn/ inth_multi2
```

```
c     NEKUSE
c
      real x,y,z,r,theta,ux,uy,uz,un,u1,u2,trx,try,trz,trn,tr1,tr2,pa
     $    ,p0,ffx,ffy,ffz,temp,flux,hc,hrad,tinf,qvol,udiff,utrans
     $    ,si2,si3,sigma,turbk,turbe,ps(ldimt)
      common /nekuse/ x  ,y  ,z  ,r  ,theta
     $              , ux ,uy ,uz 
     $              , un ,u1 ,u2 
     $              , trx,try,trz
     $              , trn,tr1,tr2,pa,p0
     $              , ffx,ffy,ffz
     $              , temp,flux,hc,hrad,tinf,qvol
     $              , udiff,utrans
     $              , si2,si3,sigma
     $              , turbk,turbe
     $              , ps

      character*3     cbu 
      common /nekusc/ cbu
```

Part of the hillpnn.f code with line numbers is

```
 c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 59       subroutine userq(ix,iy,iz,eg) ! set source term
 60 
 61 c      implicit none
 62 
 63       integer ix,iy,iz,eg
 64 
 65       include 'SIZE'
 66       include 'TOTAL'
 67       include 'NEKUSE'
 68 
 69       integer e
 70 c     e = gllel(eg)
 71 
 72       qvol   = 0.0
 73 
 74       return
 75       end
 76 c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 77       subroutine userbc(ix,iy,iz,iside,eg) ! set up boundary conditions
 78 c
 79 c     NOTE ::: This subroutine MAY NOT be called by every process
 80 c
 81 c     implicit none 
 82 
 83       integer ix,iy,iz,iside,eg
 84 
 85       include 'SIZE'
 86       include 'TOTAL'
 87       include 'NEKUSE'
 88       include 'NEKNEK'
 89 
 90      ie = gllel(eg)
 91 
 92      if (imask(ix,iy,iz,ie).eq.0) then
 93       ux   = 0.0
 94       uy   = 0.0
 95       uz   = 0.0
 96       temp = 0.0
 97      else
 98       ux = valint(ix,iy,iz,ie,1)
 99       uy = valint(ix,iy,iz,ie,2)
100       uz = valint(ix,iy,iz,ie,3)
101 
102      if (nfld_neknek.gt.3) then temp = valint(ix,iy,iz,e,ldim+2)
103      end if
104 
105 
106       return
107       end
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: In effect an `include` statements cuts and pastes the text of the included file into the including file at compile time.  Because the first error occurs in the line immediately after the last `include` statement I suspect that the inclusion leaves the code incorrect.  I suggest you look at the included files.

Comment: I agree @HighPerformanceMark about looking into the `INLUDE`d files.  One thing to be mindful of is that fixed-form source code must occupy columns 7 to 72.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark

Thank you for the direction. The only file I edited was the SIZE file and have added that code to the original question. 

Thank you again. I really appreciate the help!!

Comment: The first error specifically mentions a `COMMON` statement.  What `INCLUDE` file has a `COMMON` statement.  The error message has `hillpnn.f:97:6`.  That is line 97 and column 6.  You are using fixed-form source code.  That 6 is telling.

Comment: @evets

Thank you for explaining that. I added the two ```include``` files that have ```COMMON``` statement. Also, I added the relevant line codes for ```hillpnn.f:97:6``` as well. I am unable to spot an error in these files.

Thank you again for all your help!!

Comment: My guess  is that `ie = gllel(eq)` is starting in column 6, which then has `i` in the column that is reserved for line continuation in fixed-form source code.  The line prior to this line is a `COMMON` statement, so the compiler thinks that `e = gllel(eq)` is a continuation of the `COMMON` statement.  Your statements should start in column 7!

Comment: @evets IT WORKED!! THANK YOU!!